# Moving Object with Paint Event

Tags: c#, winforms, paint, system.drawing, paintevent

I have a test tomorrow, and we **must** use the paint event to redraw our objects, we may not use a timer.

As the MSDN says: *"The Paint event is raised when the control is redrawn."*, but that,occurs for my known, only when the form is minimized, or got invisible and back visible.

My code:

> ```
> public partial class Form1 : Form
> {
>     public Graphics drawArea;
>     public int xPos, yPos;
>
>     public Form1()
>     {
>         InitializeComponent();
>     }
>     private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
>     {
>         drawArea = e.Graphics;
>         DrawUser();
>     }
>
>     private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
>     {
>         switch (e.KeyCode)
>         { 
>             case Keys.Down:
>                 yPos++;
>                 break;
>             case Keys.Up:
>                 yPos--;
>                 break;
>             case Keys.Left:
>                 xPos--;
>                 break;
>             case Keys.Right:
>                 xPos++;
>                 break;
>         }
>     }
>
>     private void DrawUser()
>     {
>         drawArea.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Red), xPos, yPos, 50, 50);
>     }
> }
> ```

So, When I press the key arrows multiple times, the object only moves after I re-size my form. I want it to move instantly, only using the paint event.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I found it!

By adding `this.Invalidate();` after the key is pressed. This will tell the paint event to redraw.

Comment: Great find! Good job :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are tying up your form so it doesnt refresh until you move it.  Try putting [DoEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents.aspx) after your `drawArea` in `DrawUser`

```
private void DrawUser()
{
    drawArea.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Red), xPos, yPos, 50, 50);
    Application.DoEvents();
}
```

Be careful of `DoEvents` though, [it can be evil](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/12/is-doevents-evil.html).

Comment: Tried it like you said, also behind the switch statement, but it's still frozen :(

Comment: I'm looking a little closer now and see that you dont call DrawUser inside your keydown event.

Comment: That's true, If i did that, I got an error with an invalid parameter (probably the variable drawArea).

Comment: I found it, added the answer if you're interested